# Unable to Import tflite-support package. Receiving error "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying to install tflite-support package in my Anaconda Environment. These were the steps followed by me:

- Created a new python environment using `conda create --name test_env python==3.7`
- Installed tensorflow using `conda install tensorflow` (Since pip install gives import error on my PC)
- Then installed the tflite-suppport package using `pip install tflite-support` (conda install throws PackagesNotFoundError Error)

The following code snippet can be used to reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tflite_support import flatbuffers
from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata
from tflite_support import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_fb
```

Which throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-37cdba048740> in <module>
----> 1 from tflite_support import flatbuffers
      2 from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata
      3 from tflite_support import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_fb

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\testx\lib\site-packages\tflite_support\__init__.py in <module>
     28 
     29 import flatbuffers as _flatbuffers
---> 30 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata as _metadata
     31 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_schema_py_generated
     32 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import schema_py_generated as _schema_py_generated

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\testx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_lite_support\metadata\metadata.py in <module>
     32 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_fb
     33 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import schema_py_generated as _schema_fb
---> 34 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.cc.python import _pywrap_metadata_version
     35 from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.flatbuffers_lib import _pywrap_flatbuffers
     36 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried with different versions of python, tensorflow & tflite-support, but I get the same error everytime. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can give docker container a try? I had similar problems in the past and changed to docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same as you did but I didn't mention any Python version and it works fine for me.

My python version is `3.8.5`

Comment: If I don't mention the python version, I get version incompatible error since conda install picks tensorflow 2.1 version for installation, which is only compatible with python [version= ' 3.5.* | 3.6.* | 3.7.* ']

Comment: You are right my bad. I can't figure how to solve this but you also said that you can't install tensorflow via `pip`, what's the error ? Because I installed like this and didn't have any issues may be I can help here